# Fontawesome font-size change on mobile devices

Tags: font-awesome

I am trying to make social icons using round corner divs and fontawesome. It works well on my desktop computer, but on mobile the font size seems to rendered smaller.

**HTML:**

```
 <a  href="LINK" target="blank"> 
   <div class="social-icon facebook">
      <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> 
   </div>
 </a>
```

**CSS:**

```
   .social-icon{
      -moz-border-radius: 138px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 138px;
      border-radius: 138px;
      border: 5px solid;
      text-align: center;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-bottom: 15px; 
    }

    /* Facebook icon Styling */
   .social-icon.facebook {
      font-size: 20px;
      padding-top: 6px;
      border-color: #3b5998;
      background-color: #3b5998;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
```

I have tried to play around with the font awesome CSS without any luck.

Comment: Are you using any media queries which alter the font size for small-screen devices?

Comment: No. I posted my "solution" below....

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it had something to do with the lineheight which was rendered differently on my tablet/smarphone compared to my pc. This resulted in different y-posistion of the font-awesome icons. So on my pc it looked great, but on my mobile devices the icons was closer to the top. So I have set the lineheight to 1px and then i only control the y-position with padding-top.. It might not be the best solution, but it worked... however it still seems that the size of the icons differs a little on the different platform, but it is hard to tell..